# how to make a countdown timer in android from remote server controlled

Tags: php, android, countdowntimer

actually I wanted to make a countdown timer in android which needs to be like,
1. It should be a global event and should not vary by devices
2. It should be reset from database

I have seen many tutorials and I could make it very easily but the problem is how to make it dynamic like, it should be started once by admin then it should go like any scheme website or something where countdown timer once set goes down till 0 and then destroys 
thanks

Comment: have you looked at firebase functions?

Comment: no i haven't could you please elaborate it

Comment: i mean what functions you are talking about in firebase specifics